# What are the magnitude of voltage fluctuations in field surrounding the human head?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, sensor

How much would the scale of the electric field caused by neuron activity in the brain vary as it radiated from the scalp? Also what would be the typical noise level over the same space attributable to factors such as power line noise in the vicinity?

I'm not referring to the surface potentials varying across the surface of the scalp as measured by EEG (which I believe are in the range of 10 to 100 micro-volts) but instead the voltage measured say at 1mm steps away from the scalp in free space.

What if any measurement techniques are sensitive enough to measure these levels?

Comment: down voter - care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Ion currents in the neural network are responsible for the voltages detected by EEG. The electrodes are directly connected to these ion currents. There are magnetic fields associated with the ion currents and these are detected by the magnetoencephalogram. But you seem to be interested in electric fields associated with these ion currents. 
In principle there must be an electric field causing the currents inside the brain but I am not sure that there will be measurable electric fields outside the body because of these.